Voiceover accessibility for scrolling UICollection View
I am adding accessibility to my iOS App (developed using UIkit). I have enabled accessibility and added accessibility labels to all my collection view cells which is working.But I am not able to scroll up my page and only able to access limited cells in that page. How to let user know that he can scroll. There might be a way which I am unaware already tried lot of accessibility methods but no luck. Please some one show some light on this topic
